# Parent terms missing in breadcrumb path

Tags: 2013, navigation, breadcrumb, sharepoint-server, term

I have a site collection named "Faculty" and a subsite named "General".

For "General", I have multiple pages in that subsite. The content of the quick launch navigation for the subsite is based on a term set and can show up to 3 levels.
This is the structure of that term set:

```
Page 1
  Page 1-1
  Page 1-2
    Page 1-2-1
Page 2
  Page 2-1
```

When I click on "Page 1-2-1", it will have the following url in the browser: 
`http://Faculty01:81/General/SitePages/Page%201-2-1.aspx`
 

And it will show up like this in the breadcrumb trail:
**Faculty > General > Page 1-2-1**

However, I want it to show up like this:
**Faculty > General > Page 1 > Page 1-2 > Page 1-2-1**

Could someone help me to achieve this? 
*Help and/or suggestions are appreciated!*

(Notes: 
Publishing features have been enabled and I'm working with SharePoint Server 2013. I use SharePoint Designer 2013 to make changes in the master page.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by setting the navigation to term driven navigation, this however created a new problem with the quick launch not showing the parent terms. 
New solution! Please check the answer to [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67584/how-do-i-create-a-term-driven-breadcrumb-trail/88590#88590).

Comment: how to solve this? any other soltions?

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet, but I no longer need this so I just gave up searching. I suppose it could be done with C# though, but I didn't dig that one through.

Comment: New answer! I have solved a different question I asked a while ago, but the solution is also applicable to this problem. Please see the link in my answer.