# (Parent) terms missing from quick launch

Tags: navigation, taxonomy, quick-launch, term

I have a term set, built up like this:

```
Page 1
  Page 1-1
  Page 1-2
    Page 1-2-1
    Page 1-2-2
Page 2
  Page 2-1
```

It is set up to be used for site navigation, and is based on term-driven pages. The whole term set uses "/General/Pages/Intro.aspx" as the target page, all child terms inherit this. 
Also, the quick launch has been set up to support up to 6 static display levels.

If I click on "Page 1-2-1", it will show me a correct breadcrumb trail:

```
Page 1 > Page 1-2 > Page 1-2-1
```

**BUT**! It won't show me a correct Quick Launch navigation. The navigation on the left hand side has been somewhat trimmed. It should display just like in the term set (see top of question), but instead it just shows the current page and its sibling(s), like this:

```
Page 1-2-1
Page 1-2-2
```

So it doesn't show any parent element anymore, no parent terms are displayed. 
For the SiteMapPath I use the SPContentMapProvider as a sitemap provider, I wish to keep this (so I'm not planning on switching to CurrentNavSiteMapProviderNoEncode).
Here's a screenshot of how the navigation on the left should look like (text is in Dutch tho, but that's not relevant here). 
[image: Navigation with all terms]

And here's a screenshot of what the navigation looks like when I am on the page named "Proces". As you see here, the breadcrumb trail shows the correct path, but now the parent terms of "Proces" are gone. I just want the navigation to look the same all the time, like in the first screenshot.
[image: Navigation with no parent terms]

Basically in the menu, it just shows the term you're currently on and whatever siblings that term has, but it doesn't show the parent terms. Which is not supposed to happen. 
Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
This question was marked as a duplicate of [this post here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67770/parent-terms-missing-in-breadcrumb-path), however in that other post I was talking about parents missing from the breadcrumb trail while in this post, I am talking about parents missing from the quick launch. I managed to solve my other post myself by using term driven navigation, yet this created a new issue which I ask about in this post. Hence, the question asked here is not a duplicate.

SECOND EDIT:
Just to clarify, the problem only occurs with term-driven navigation. The pages have the publishing page content type. 
The problem does not happen when using only simple navigation links (with only wiki pages), but I can't apply this workaround since I really need users to be able to check in/out and publish these pages.

Comment: I edited my question (this one), since it's not a duplicate. In this question I'm asking about terms inside the quick launch, not the breadcrumb. I managed to solve the breadcrumb issue (about which I asked in a different question), but it gave me another problem (asked about in this question).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question. I have re-opened it.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118329/sharepoint-2013-metadata-navigation-show-parent-term/118602

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved it for now.

I changed the navigation in the term set from "Term-Driven Page with Friendly URL" to "Simple Link or Header". While I now no longer have a friendly URL, it at least makes my side navigation work again.

Comment: Magali, Did you ever get an answer to this?
I've been struggling for a while now and thought I would revisit the issue to try and find an answer. Or did you just stick with Simple Link or Header? Thanks in advance
John.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't, I just kept on using the term-driven navigation with "Simple Link or Header".